# How to move a diacritical mark one letter to the left

Tags: python

I'm using this regular expression to remove an Arabic diacritical mark from a subtitle file, could it be modified to move the diacritical mark just one letter to the left instead of removing it? I'm using python 2.7.

```
file_content = re.sub(u'\u0651', '', file_content)
```

This is the original line in a subtitle file the diacritical mark is in its correct place

أنا لا أترصّد عبر الإنترنت

This is how i need it to be

أنا لا أترصدّ عبر الإنترنت

I'm using a media player that for some reason moves the diacritical mark one letter to the right, so to get the diacritical mark in its correct place when using this media player i need to move the diacritical mark one letter to the left in the subtitle file.

https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/issues/17076

Comment: Are the marks before or after the original letter?

Comment: I meant in the actual string. We're dealing with an abstraction here, so the visual representation is irrelevant for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: This is the original line

‫أنا لا أترصّد عبر الإنترنت

Comment: This how i need it to be

‫أنا لا أترصدّ عبر الإنترنت

Comment: Could you dump you Unicode points for this string?

Comment: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%A7+%D9%84%D8%A7+%D8%A3%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%B5%D9%91%D8%AF+%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%B1+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AA

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0651/index.htm

Comment: I updated the post with a new code.

Comment: The mark is after the original letter.

Comment: The original letter with the mark in the example above its name is ARABIC LETTER SAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your diacritics work in Unicode exactly, but in general, you have to make the following type of replacement in your string:

```
x' -> 'x
```

This is easy to do with a single substitution:

```
file_content = re.sub('(.)([ًٌٍَُِّ])', r'\2\1', file_content)
```

This assumes of course that you have only a single diacritic before/after a letter, and that the diacritic is a separate Unicode character every time.

Comment: Thank you, could not get to work, i updated the post.

Comment: It works only if i changed it to

file_content = re.sub(u'(.)\u0651', '\u0651\\1', file_content)

Comment: and i get this

‫أنا لا أترّصد عبر الإنترنت

Comment: when i need

‫أنا لا أترصدّ عبر الإنترنت

Comment: the original text is this

أنا لا أترصّد عبر الإنترنت

Comment: file_content = re.sub(u'(.)\u0651', u'\u0651\\1', file_content)

Comment: the change is from u'\u0651\1' to u'\u0651\\1'

Comment: @Egy253. I've updated my answer with what I think your findings mean.

Comment: I tried

 file_content = re.sub(u'(.)(\u0651)', r'\2\1', file_content)

Comment: I get

أنا لا أترّصد عبر الإنترنت

Comment: I need

أنا لا أترصدّ عبر الإنترنت

Comment: Look at the Unicode and figure out how to do it. I've shown you how to transpose two characters.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me

file_content = re.sub(u'(\u0651)(.)', r'\2\1', file_content)

Comment: @Egy253. You could of course do that with regex, but I wouldn't recommend nailing everything with the same hammer. A simple `if` statement would make the code much more legible, in my opinion: `if file_content[-1] in '...': file_content += ' '`.

Comment: @Egy253. If you need more detailed help, feel free to ask another question, and ping me here so I can go take a look at it.

Comment: @Egy253. Please don't post long code (or questions) in the comments. Ask another question if you believe you have a specific enough problem that you can't get around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205452/discussion-between-egy253-and-mad-physicist).